# CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn works with x86 compile but not x64

Tags: c++, mfc, 64-bit, rtf, cricheditctrl

I am writing in C++ using MFC under Visual Studio 2022.
I have a CRichEditCtrl embedded in a dialog, and I want to feed it pre-formatted text markup written with an external RTF editor. In the end I want to embed the text within the program (to avoid having an external file), and so far as I can see the only way to do this is by putting the text into a CMemFile and then using CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn. If there is a better way of doing this I'd like to hear about it.
However, to start off I just tried to read from an external RFT file using the example code from the MSoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(AFXCMN%252FCRichEditCtrl)%3Bk(CRichEditCtrl)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170#streamin).
For completion, here is my code version:

```
CFile cFile(TEXT("NeuroSimHelp.rtf"), CFile::modeRead);  
EDITSTREAM es;  
es.dwCookie = (DWORD)&cFile;  
es.pfnCallback = FileStreamInCallback;  
m_HelpRTF.StreamIn(SF_RTF, es);
```

```
static DWORD CALLBACK FileStreamInCallback(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG* pcb);
```

```
static DWORD CALLBACK FileStreamInCallback(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG* pcb)  
{  
    CFile* pFile = (CFile*)dwCookie;  
    *pcb = pFile->Read(pbBuff, cb);  
    return 0;  
}
```

This compiles and runs fine in x86 mode, but fails to compile in x64 mode.
The problem lies in the line:
`es.pfnCallback = FileStreamInCallback;`
which generates the compile error:
`error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'DWORD (__cdecl *)(DWORD,LPBYTE,LONG,LONG *)' to 'EDITSTREAMCALLBACK'`
As I said, this compiles and works in x86, so I guess the 64-bit callback function address does not fit into the DWORD_PTR dwCookie in EDITSTREAMCALLBACK type.
I'm probably missing something obvious, but if anyone knows how to fix this the  help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Bill H

Comment: 1st argument is supposed to be DWORD_PTR, not DWORD. Obviously they differ in size on 64 bit but not 32.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. Changing DWORD to DWORD_PTR in both the cast and the callback argument type fixed it, - although I also had to cast the callback allocation es.pfnCallback = EDITSTREAMCALLBACK(FileStreamInCallback);
The Microsoft documentation example code needs a work-over.
I don't seem to be able to mark your comment as an answer, but it is.

Comment: If you need to cast the callback function pointer then it doesn't have the correct signature. The most common mismatch is the encoded calling convention (identified by `CALLBACK`). The cast is thus not a solution rather than obscuring a bug.

Comment: Turns out the cast ISN'T actually necessary - I don't now know why I thought it was. Must have been left over from a previous attempt to solve my original problem. Anyway, the change from DWORD to DWORD_PTR did the job. Thanks you both for your help.